# Text navigation through left and right arrows doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu 16.06 and I'm having the following problem. Left and right arrows navigation through text doesn't work anywhere, nor console no any editor or browser.

What is suspicious, when I'm running xev, I see the following. When I press arrows up and down:

```
 KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x50a, subw 0x0, time 5603186, (-756,-476), root:(2035,0),
    state 0x0, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x50a, subw 0x0, time 5603250, (-756,-476), root:(2035,0),
    state 0x0, keycode 111 (keysym 0xff52, Up), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x50a, subw 0x0, time 5604250, (-756,-476), root:(2035,0),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x50a, subw 0x0, time 5604314, (-756,-476), root:(2035,0),
    state 0x0, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

that is, legit key press and release events, and when I press arrows left and right:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    atom 0x14d (_NET_WM_STATE), time 5704210, state PropertyNewValue

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Looks like some weird mappings are in place, but where are they set and how can I reset them?